# How to use a component inside a translation with angular and ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

What is correct way to insert some angular components inside translation strings?

I am working on angular single page app and now I need to add some translation. Before adding translations I wrote like this:

```
<p>
You can find an email to contact us on the  <a routerLink="/contacts">contacts page</a>.
<p>
```

But after added translation (for translate my app I use ngx-translate) all my strings stored in json and construction like this doesn't work:

```
<p [innerHTML]="'contacts_phrase_key' | translate">
```

Here is a little [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-irtatb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: there is no good way to do that. you have to split your phrase into several pieces. at least one for the phrase outside of the like and one for the link

Comment: Yes, I thought about this but in different languages place where I have to insert component may be in different places that's why I decline this idea

Comment: you can insert something like a button, and add event listeners (for navigation) programmatically. but I would postpone this idea untill you really really need it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.